# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3

Tags: build.gradle

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.3/gradle-8.3.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Android studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch1
java version 20.0.2
I want to resolve an error.